# Why is #{} not adding the value to the string?

Tags: ruby, httparty

Using `httparty` I'm making a GET request to:

```
https://api.marktplaats.nl/api3/categories.json?oauth_token=1me6jq76h8t6rim747m7bketkd&api_ver=3.7&session=ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595&screenWidth=62&screenHeight=111&app_ver=Android3.1.0
```

Code A:

```
require 'httparty'

class Marktplaats  
  def categories
    HTTParty.get('https://api.marktplaats.nl/api3/categories.json?oauth_token=1me6jq76h8t6rim747m7bketkd&api_ver=3.7&session=ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595&screenWidth=62&screenHeight=111&app_ver=Android3.1.0')
  end
end
```

Code B:

```
require 'httparty'

class Marktplaats
  @oauth_token = '1me6jq76h8t6rim747m7bketkd'

  def categories
    HTTParty.get("https://api.marktplaats.nl/api3/categories.json?oauth_token=#{@oauth_token}&api_ver=3.7&session=ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595&screenWidth=62&screenHeight=111&app_ver=Android3.1.0")
  end
end
```

When doing:

```
m = Marktplaats.new
m.categories
```

Code A works, but Code B doesn't.

Calling `.request.last_uri.to_s` on the GET call of Code B returns:

```
https://api.marktplaats.nl/api3/categories.json?oauth_token=&api_ver=3.7&session=ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595&screenWidth=62&screenHeight=111&app_ver=Android3.1.0
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: My suggestion is to use *constant*, if the value doesn't vary as per the instances...

Comment: Get in the habit of using the built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module, or [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) to manipulate URLs. They'll handle encoding issues for you that directly injecting into strings won't cover.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case of defining a variable at the *class-level* versus the *instance-level*.  You have defined `@oauth_token` at the class-level, but are trying to use it at the instance-level and can't.  Try changing your code to this:

```
class Marktplaats
  def initialize
    @oauth_token = '1me6jq76h8t6rim747m7bketkd'
  end

  def categories
    HTTParty.get("https://api.marktplaats.nl/api3/categories.json?oauth_token=#{@oauth_token}&api_ver=3.7&session=ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595&screenWidth=62&screenHeight=111&app_ver=Android3.1.0")
  end
end
```

OR to this, which uses a constant that is accessible at both the class and instance levels (but should never change).:

```
class Marktplaats
  OAUTH_TOKEN = '1me6jq76h8t6rim747m7bketkd'

  def categories
    HTTParty.get("https://api.marktplaats.nl/api3/categories.json?oauth_token=#{OAUTH_TOKEN}&api_ver=3.7&session=ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595&screenWidth=62&screenHeight=111&app_ver=Android3.1.0")
  end
end
```

Comment: That's not a class variable. It's an instance variable in the class object. A subtle, but important, distinction.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a class-instance variable, but using a local instance variable in your method. Do this instead:

```
require 'httparty'

class Marktplaats
  OAUTH_TOKEN= '1me6jq76h8t6rim747m7bketkd'

  def categories
    HTTParty.get("https://api.marktplaats.nl/api3/categories.json?oauth_token=#{OAUTH_TOKEN}&api_ver=3.7&session=ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595&screenWidth=62&screenHeight=111&app_ver=Android3.1.0")
  end
end
```