# Why is '+' being converted into '%2B' and how do I prevent this?

Tags: ruby, uri, urldecode, httparty

I'm making a GET request to search for certain listings. The keyword I'm testing is `iphone 5`.

When doing:

```
m = Marktplaats.new
m.search(keyword: 'iphone 5')
```

I get irrelevant data.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
require 'httparty'

class Marktplaats
  include HTTParty

  base_uri('https://api.marktplaats.nl')

  def search(keyword)

    # Debug
    puts search_query_params(keyword)
    puts last_uri(self.class.get('/api3/ads.json', query: search_query_params(keyword)))

    self.class.get('/api3/ads.json', query: search_query_params(keyword))
  end

  def view(urn)
    self.class.get("/api3/ads/#{urn}.json", query: default_query_params)
  end

  def categories
    self.class.get('/api3/categories.json', query: default_query_params)
  end

  protected

    def default_query_params
      {
        oauth_token: '1me6jq76h8t6rim747m7bketkd',
        api_ver: '3.7',
        session: 'ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595',
        screenWidth: '62',
        screenHeight: '111',
        app_ver: 'Android3.1.0'
      }
    end

    def search_query_params(args = {})
      search_params = {
        q: split_keyword(args[:keyword]),
        searchOnTitleAndDescription: args[:search_on_title_and_description] || 'false',
        showListings: args[:show_listings] || 'true',
        categoryId: args[:category_id] || '1953',
        page: args[:page] || '1',
        size: args[:size] || '30',
        sortBy: args[:sort_by] || 'DEFAULT',
        sortOrder: args[:sort_order] || 'DESCENDING',
        showHistograms: args[:show_histograms] || 'true'
      }
      merge_params(default_query_params, search_params)
    end

    def merge_params(params1, params2)
      params1.merge(params2)
    end

    def split_keyword(keyword)
      keyword.gsub(' ', '+')
    end

    def last_uri(last_request)
      last_request.request.last_uri
    end
end
```

`puts search_query_params(keyword)` returns:

```
{:oauth_token=>"1me6jq76h8t6rim747m7bketkd", :api_ver=>"3.7", :session=>"ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595", :screenWidth=>"62", :screenHeight=>"111", :app_ver=>"Android3.1.0", :q=>"iphone+5", :searchOnTitleAndDescription=>"true", :showListings=>"false", :categoryId=>"1953", :page=>"1", :size=>"30", :sortBy=>"DEFAULT", :sortOrder=>"DESCENDING", :showHistograms=>"true"}
```

and `last_uri(self.class.get('/api3/ads.json', query: search_query_params(keyword)))` returns:

```
https://api.marktplaats.nl/api3/ads.json?oauth_token=1me6jq76h8t6rim747m7bketkd&api_ver=3.7&session=ebc565b8-659f-40f6-9d0a-96986f1d1595&screenWidth=62&screenHeight=111&app_ver=Android3.1.0&q=iphone%2B5&searchOnTitleAndDescription=false&showListings=true&categoryId=1953&page=1&size=30&sortBy=DEFAULT&sortOrder=DESCENDING&showHistograms=true
```

I think it has something to do with the request URI. The `+` symbol between keywords is shown as `%2B`. So `iphone+5` is show as `iphone%2B5`. If I replace `iphone%2B5` with `iphone+5` in the URI it returns the correct data.

The question is how do I prevent the `+` symbol being converted into `%2B` when making a GET request with HTTParty?

Note:
This probably is what [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man) was talking about when he commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893661/why-is-not-adding-the-value-to-the-string?noredirect=1#comment38670875_24893661).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the `#split_keyword(keyword)` method from the class, thus not using it anymore.

It seems that I didn't need to manually replace the `' '` in between words with `+` symbols. If I do, they get converted to `%2B` which doesn't seem to work.

Without the manual replacement, the `' '` get converted to `%20`, which does work.